# 'American Sniper' : Reality about the movie's end?

Tags: character, american-sniper

In the movie, they don't offer any explanation for the killer's actions. Since this is based on a true story, I was kind of hoping someone knows why he did it. I'm not from the US, but I expect there was considerable news coverage of the tragedy and some explanation is out there.

I searched the internet but was unable to find a story that sheds some light on the event.

Comment: Not sure how it is relevant to the movie or it's story. Seems more of a question about the real life character.....

Comment: Agree with @KeyBrdBasher ... this is about Kyle, not about his killer. The story of his killer is still ongoing in the court system. [Here's some back story, if you like](http://www.wcvb.com/national/american-snipers-accused-killer-stands-trial/31207410) about what happened and the trial.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the details of the life of the lead character in the movie. The question as such has nothing to do with the movie.

Comment: As it was part of the movie, surely it's a question that's relevant to the movie, no?

Comment: When a filmmaker chooses to turn someone's life into a movie, it's his job to provide all the answers. It's not like American Sniper is one hundred percent fact. They did use artistic license to alter some events. It wasn't a documentary. So I disagree with those who say the question is not related to the movie. Not providing answers, imo, is what makes or breaks a biopic. Case in point: J. Edgar.

Comment: @Tushar - I'll counter that by asking this question about a character most of us recognize from the original Star Wars trilogy; is it relevant **why** Boba Fett is a bounty hunter?  No.  It's just enought to know that he **is** one.  I think that's the thought process behind Routh.  Like you said, it's not a documentary.  It's a tidbit about a character you never even really meet in a movie.  This is why, technically, this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

Kyle's accused killer, Eddie Routh, has never stated why he killed Kyle and another veteran, Chad Littlefield, that day.  All that's known is that Kyle and Littlefield took Routh, who suffers from PTSD, to the gun range that day, and that a hunting guide later found Kyle and Littlefield dead on another part of the property.  Kyle's truck was missing, and Routh was nowhere to be found.

**UPDATE**

I happened to stumble over this old answer and did a quick search; Routh [later admitted that he shot the two men](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/eddie-ray-routh-shot-american-sniper-chris-kyle-because-they-n306126) on the way to the range because "they wouldn't talk to me.   I was just riding in the back seat of the truck and nobody would talk to me. They were just taking me to the range so I shot them. I feel bad about it, but they wouldn't talk to me. I am sure they have forgiven me."